# Set the Jlabel to respond to the Jbuttons, but when I click on the button nothing is responding

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlabel

I set the button according to the 1-13 numbers on game card. When I click on a button I want it to randomly draw a card from the deck. If the card doesn't match the button # then I can try another button, if the card match the button # then the game ends. The program will keep running through 52 cards as long as the button and the card doesn't match. lblpic is where the card image suppose to appear when the user click one of the number button. I can't get the buttons to work properly. I fixed some codes in my Card game, but it's still not working. I also can't get the card image to show up when the user click on a number button. I tried linking the ImageLoader class to the CardGame Jframe, but it's not wokring.

ImageLoader

```
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    public class ImageLoader {
        public final ImageIcon BACK  = new ImageIcon("img/backbluepattern.gif");
        public ImageIcon[][] cardImg = new ImageIcon[4][13];
        public final String[] SUITS = {"clubs", "hearts", "spades", "diamonds"};

        public ImageLoader() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 13; j++) {
                    String strBuf = "img/" +  SUITS[i] + j + ".gif";
                    cardImg[i][j-1] = new ImageIcon(strBuf);
                }
            }
        }

    }

Card    

    public class Card {
        //Numerical equivalent of the suit and face
        private int suitNum; // valid range is 0 - 3
        private int faceNum; // valid range is 0 - 12
        //For converting between names and numbers
        public static final String[] SUITS = {"Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds"};
        public static final String[] FACES = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", 
            "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

        //Constructor takes combined number and splits it to suit and face numbers
        public Card(int num) {
            if (num > 51) {
                System.out.println("Input number is larger than 51.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            suitNum = num / 13;
            faceNum = num % 13;
        }

        // Return a calculated value that combines suit and face numbers
        public int getTotalNumber() {
            return (this.suitNum * 13 + this.faceNum);
        }

        public int getFaceNumber() {
            return faceNum;
        }

        public int getSuitNumber() {
            return suitNum;
        }

        public String toString() {
            int num = getTotalNumber();
            String outStr = FACES[num % 13];
            outStr += " of ";
            outStr += SUITS[num / 13];
            return outStr;
        }
    }

Deck    

    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Stack;

    public class Deck extends Stack<Card>{ 
        //pop method already in the stack 

        // Create a new shuffled deck
        public Deck() {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 52; ii++) {
                push(new Card(ii));
            }
            Collections.shuffle(this);
        }

        // For debug purposes
        public void printDeck() {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 52; ii++) {
                System.out.println(get(ii).toString());
            }
        }   
    }

CardGame

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;



public CardGame() {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                CardGame window = new CardGame();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        lblpic = new JLabel("");
        Image img = new ImageIcon BACK(this getClass().getResource("img/backbluepattern.gif")).getImage();
        lblpic.getIcon(new ImageIcon(img)); 


        JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
        btn1.setBounds(4, 13, 97, 25);
        btn1.addActionListener(new Btn1ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn1);

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
        btn2.setBounds(4, 51, 97, 25);
        btn2.addActionListener(new Btn2ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn2);

        JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
        btn3.setBounds(4, 89, 97, 25);
        btn3.addActionListener(new Btn3ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn3);

        JButton btn4 = new JButton("4");
        btn4.setBounds(4, 127, 97, 25);
        btn4.addActionListener(new Btn4ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn4);

        JButton btn5 = new JButton("5");
        btn5.setBounds(4, 165, 97, 25);
        btn5.addActionListener(new Btn5ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn5);

        JButton btn6 = new JButton("6");
        btn6.setBounds(4, 203, 97, 25);
        btn6.addActionListener(new Btn6ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn6);

        JButton btn7 = new JButton("7");
        btn7.setBounds(113, 13, 97, 25);
        btn7.addActionListener(new Btn7ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn7);

        JButton btn8 = new JButton("8");
        btn8.setBounds(113, 51, 97, 25);
        btn8.addActionListener(new Btn8ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn8);

        JButton btn9 = new JButton("9");
        btn9.setBounds(113, 89, 97, 25);
        btn9.addActionListener(new Btn9ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn9);

        JButton btn10 = new JButton("10");
        btn10.setBounds(113, 127, 97, 25);
        btn10.addActionListener(new Btn10ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn10);

        JButton btn11 = new JButton("11");
        btn11.setBounds(113, 165, 97, 25);
        btn11.addActionListener(new Btn11ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn11);

        JButton btn12 = new JButton("12");
        btn12.setBounds(113, 203, 97, 25);
        btn12.addActionListener(new Btn12ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn12);

        JButton btn13 = new JButton("13");
        btn13.setBounds(222, 13, 97, 25);
        btn13.addActionListener(new Btn13ActionListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn13);

        lblpic = new JLabel("");
        lblpic.setBounds(222, 51, 115, 177);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblpic);
    }

    private class Btn1ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
        }
    private class Btn2ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
        }
    private class Btn3ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
        }
    private class Btn4ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
        }
    private class Btn5ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
    }
    private class Btn6ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
        }
    private class Btn7ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
        }
    private class Btn8ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
        }
    private class Btn9ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
        }
    private class Btn10ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
        }
    private class Btn11ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
        }
    private class Btn12ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
        }
    private class Btn13ActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card One = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (One.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + One);

            if (One.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First take a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).  Only `btn1` is registered a instance of `BtnNewButtonActionListener `

Comment: What's the association between the card and the button?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would put aside Window Builder, it's not doing you any favors.

Next, you need to attach an `ActionListener` to EACH button, in your case, you can use the same instance of `ActionListener` for each button as it will basically be doing the same thing.

Next, when the `ActionListener` is triggered, you need to ascertain which button was clicked.  There's are number of ways to do this, but in your case, the `actionCommand` of the `ActionEvent` will be the text of the button, which is a number (in `String` format), so we can use that.  Next, we need to calculate the card that the button represents, this is harder, as there are 52 cards, but only 13 cards.  Assuming we only care about the value of the card and not it's face, we can use the `Card` from the deck to determine the suit.

Once we have both `Card`s, we can compare them, for that, you could simply use the `equals` method of the `Card`

## Card

```
public class Card {

    //...

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 97 * hash + this.suitNum;
        hash = 97 * hash + this.faceNum;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Card other = (Card) obj;
        if (this.suitNum != other.suitNum) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.faceNum != other.faceNum) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

## BtnNewButtonActionListener

```
private class BtnNewButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Card card = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

        int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
        int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (card.getSuitNumber() * 13);
        Card match = new Card(cardValue);

        System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + card);

        if (card.equals(match)) {
            System.out.println("Winner");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Loser");
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, a runnable example, because that's a lot of information to take in...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Stack;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class CardGame {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel lblA;
    private Deck B = new Deck(); //B have 52 cards, and shuffled  

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CardGame window = new CardGame();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public CardGame() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
        gbc.ipadx = 15;
        gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;

        for (int index = 0; index < 13; index++) {

            System.out.println(index + " - " + (index % 3));

            gbc.gridx = index / 6;
            gbc.gridy = index % 6;

            JButton btn1 = new JButton(Integer.toString(index + 1));
            btn1.addActionListener(new BtnNewButtonActionListener());
            frame.getContentPane().add(btn1, gbc);

        }
    }

    private class BtnNewButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Card card = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (card.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + card);

            if (card.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Winner");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Loser");
            }
        }

    }

    public static class Card {

        //Numerical equivalent of the suit and face
        private int suitNum; // valid range is 0 - 3
        private int faceNum; // valid range is 0 - 12
        //For converting between names and numbers
        public static final String[] SUITS = {"Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds"};
        public static final String[] FACES = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
            "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

        //Constructor takes combined number and splits it to suit and face numbers
        public Card(int num) {
            if (num > 51) {
                System.out.println("Input number is larger than 51.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            suitNum = num / 13;
            faceNum = num % 13;
        }

        // Return a calculated value that combines suit and face numbers
        public int getTotalNumber() {
            return (this.suitNum * 13 + this.faceNum);
        }

        public int getFaceNumber() {
            return faceNum;
        }

        public int getSuitNumber() {
            return suitNum;
        }

        public String toString() {
            int num = getTotalNumber();
            String outStr = FACES[num % 13];
            outStr += " of ";
            outStr += SUITS[num / 13];
            return outStr;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 97 * hash + this.suitNum;
            hash = 97 * hash + this.faceNum;
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Card other = (Card) obj;
            if (this.suitNum != other.suitNum) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.faceNum != other.faceNum) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    public class Deck extends Stack<Card> {
        //pop method already in the stack 

        // Create a new shuffled deck
        public Deck() {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 52; ii++) {
                push(new Card(ii));
            }
            Collections.shuffle(this);
        }

        // For debug purposes
        public void printDeck() {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 52; ii++) {
                System.out.println(get(ii).toString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Have a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: I know there are 52 cards in a deck. The buttons represent the 13 numbers on the cards in the deck. For example the user will press 12 and the card will random draw from the deck, then if it doesn't match the number the user click then they can pick a different number to guess until both card and the number button matches. Sorry I was not clear about this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do I need to use this code: Card card = B.pop(); //Card one is from Deck B, need to compare to the button

            int actionValue = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
            int cardValue = (actionValue - 1) + (card.getSuitNumber() * 13);
            Card match = new Card(cardValue);

            System.out.println("Match " + match + " to " + card);

            if (card.equals(match)) {
                System.out.println("Winner");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Loser");
            } for all 13 buttons?

Comment: Well, pretty much. If you have a look at the runnable example, I simply create an instance of `BtnNewButtonActionListener` for each button, `btn1.addActionListener(new BtnNewButtonActionListener());`, technically you could use the same instance in this.  This is just code reduction on my part so I'm not replicating code.  Since you're only interested in the card numbers, you could do away with the creation of the second card and simply compare the numerical values ;)

Comment: It's still not working. I just update the new codes, can you check it please.

Comment: Why not just re-use `BtnNewButtonActionListener`?

Comment: Your code won't compile because `e` is undefined in the `Btn1ActionListener#actionPerformed` method, change `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {` to `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {`

Comment: Because I thought I have to do it for each buttons for them to work. I didn't know you can use one code for all the buttons. How would you do that? I don't understand it. I'm sorry I slow at this. I watched youtube video, and read forum but I still don't understand it.

Comment: As you can see from my example, I simple create a new instance of the same ActionListener for each button, but in your case, you could create a single instance of the ActionListener and apply it to every button